# Converting multidimensional SimpleXML to associative array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a nested multidimensional XML string that I get into `SimpleXML`. I want to convert it into an associative array. The examples listed on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ro/book.simplexml.php) do not work correctly or they do only for flat xmls.

Comment: Please add sample input and desired output.  Then what is your SimpleXML code?

Comment: Why do you need this as an array?  It may be easier to work with the XML content as it is.

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of examples of doing this. You haven't even said what "doesn't work correctly" about the ones you've already found, so it's hard to see how a new example here will be any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works better than the example on SimpleXML manual page, but in its current form it discards the attributes.

```
function xml2array($xmlObject, $out = array())
{
    foreach ($xmlObject as $node) {
        if ($node->count() > 0) {
            $out[$node->getName()][] = xml2array($node);
        } else {
            $out[$node->getName()] = (string)$node;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Add going through arguments then: `foreach ($node->attributes() as $key => $val) { $out[$node->getName()][$key] = $val; }`

Comment: @raina77ow ...at which point you quickly discover why flattening XML to an array is a pain, because an attribute could have the same name as a child element. Which is pretty much why SimpleXML exists, so that you don't need to.

Comment: I don't really think it's actually a problem, as you can delay filling the attributes and exclude (or deal in some other way) the duplicates. The question is, shouldn't authors prevent such cases? XML Schemas, aren't they useful those days still? )

Comment: @raina77ow Why should they? It's perfectly valid in XML to write `<person id="42"><id type="passport">...</id></person>`. And that's just one of many, many problems you will have writing a generic transform like this. Again, SimpleXML is explicitly designed to give you access to all the data without any of these problems, so why not just use it?

Comment: @IMSoP Cannot use it without rewriting a whole library deployed in production. Must work within the confines, this is the real world.

Comment: @vladimir.gorea I can understand not being able to pass around SimpleXML objects, but if you're in control of the transform, you can and should write a specific transform to turn the specific XML you're handling into the specific array the rest of the code is expecting. Trying to write a single library function which converts all instances of valid XML into a consistent array structure is doomed to failure. `raina77ow`'s suggestion seems to be that all authors of XML should limit themselves to an arbitrary subset that makes life easier; that is not how the real world works either.